# Power for lav mic plugged into a Zoom H5?

Tags: audio-recording, microphone

I have a handheld Zoom H5 recorder and just ordered a lav mic ([Voice Technologies VT4001](http://www.vt-switzerland.com/en/vt401-omni-lavalier-microphone)).

The [Zoom's spec sheet](http://www.zoom.co.jp/products/h5/spec/) lists its inputs as 2 "XLR/TRS combo jacks" capable of providing phantom power at +12V, +24V and +48V.

I will be using the lav wired.

Question: which is the simplest way to connect and power this mic from this recorder? Do I need some sort of adapter or will a simple mic jack <=> TRS cable do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an electret power supply that accepts phantom power and then will hook it up via a standard XLR cable to the H5.  If you have the bare wire version, you will also need a connector to put on the bare wire so that it can tie in to the electret power supply.  You will also need to make sure that +48v phantom power is turned on on the H5.  (Alternately you could use a battery powered electret power supply, but I'd recommend sticking to using phantom since it is available.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would something like [this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/327244-REG/Ambient_Recording_EMP35_P48_Electret_Converter_for.html) solve it by itself?

Comment: @laramichaels that is the power supply portion. You still need a cable end for the mic to be able to plug in.